# Is it possible to make a port unavailable for binding in Linux?

Tags: port-forwarding, port

I'm working on a port forwarding problem.

Is it possible to make a port unavailable for binding in Linux? I have an application that will dynamically listen on port 5000-10000, however, I don't want the application to ever bind to port 5555.

Is there an easy to block this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [portreserve](https://linux.die.net/man/1/portreserve) and create a file in `/etc/portreserve` containing `5555`.

portreserve is available at [several distributions](https://pkgs.org/download/portreserve) and comes with pre-configured systemd service file.

If you wish to use port 5555 for another thing afterwards, you need to run `portrelease [name-of-your-file]`